# How to increment a value, given a key in a java hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

If I have the following:

```
public enum Attribute {
     ONE, TWO, THREE
}

private Map<String, Integer> mAttributesMap = new HashMap<>();

mAttributesMap.put(Attribute.ONE.name(), 5);
mAttributesMap.put(Attribute.TWO.name(), 5);
```

So how can I get the key of `mAttibutesMap`? And how to increment it?

Comment: Maps have `get` and `put` methods, did you try using them to retrieve the value, increment it and set it again? Please post your attempts

Comment: Why is it a `Map<String, Integer>` and not `Map<Attribute, Integer>`?

Comment: Please think about accept an answer, this is how a forum works, and a new user would be more attracted from accepted post than non-accepted post

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1.** First you could directly use a `Map<Attribute , Integer>` and `put` like this :

```
mAttributesMap.put(Attribute.ONE, 5);
mAttributesMap.put(Attribute.TWO, 5);
```

---

**2.** To increment the value of a key, you can do as follow, get the value, and `put` it again with `+1`, because the `key` already exists it will just replace the existing one (keys in a map are **unique**) :

```
public void incrementValueFromKey(Attribute key){
    mAttributesMap.computeIfPresent(key, (k, v) -> v + 1);
}
```

---

**3.** To have a more generic solution you could do :

```
public void incrementValueFromKey(Attribute key, int increment){
    mAttributesMap.computeIfPresent(key, (k, v) -> v + increment);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not edit directly a map, but you can replace a value using:

```
mAttributesMap.put(Attribute.ONE.name(), 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the key exists in the HashMap, you can do the following:

```
int currentValue = mAttributesMap.get(Attribute.ONE.name());
mAttributesMap.put(Attribute.ONE.name(), currentValue+1);
```

If the key may or may not exist in the HashMap, you can do the following:

```
int currentValue = 0;
if (mAttributesMap.containsKey(Attribute.ONE.name())) {
  currentValue = mAttributesMap.get(Attribute.ONE.name());
}
mAttributesMap.put(Attribute.ONE.name(), currentValue+1);
```

I hope this helps you! Thank you. Peace.

p.s. This is my updated version of David Geirola's answer on Mar 22 '18 at 8:22.